# C# Windows Services Alternative

Tags: c#

Could anyone please tell me whether there is any alternative to Windows Services? The reason for my question is that I find windows services hard to test as it requires it be installed first.

Thank you.

Comment: Your statement: "The reason for my question is that I find windows services hard to test as it requires it be installed first.", I would like to say on this that you can test your window service by first writing its whole code on a button's click in a Form. After you get satisfied with your code of a Form, you can copy and paste that code into Service.cs file.

Comment: I have to agree with OP on this one, services are harder to troubleshoot, especially on production environment. But yes, there are ways to mitigate that problem, by writing your code run as a console/win form first.. For installation problem & privileges, your best bet is logging & event viewer though

Answer (score 16):

Check out the [Topshelf project](http://topshelf-project.com/). Simplicity of a console application, but can installed as a windows service.

Answer (score 5):

This just requires properly organizing and factoring your code so it doesn't *need* to be called from the service method.  I.E., you have a function call that runs everything - which can either be called from the service, or by your Main method - or by NUnit, etc.

Otherwise, if you still want an alternative, you could write everything within the Main method, and then run your program as part of a Windows Scheduled Task.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not as simple as that. You will have run time errors specific to the windows service like installation problems, logging, access violations etc that are hard to test. You can attach debugger to the process but still it is not a desirable way to find out the errors.

Answer (score 4):

Your best alternative to Windows Services is [Windows Server AppFabric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677312%28v=azure.10%29.aspx).  Here is good [blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2010/09/08/death-to-windows-services-long-live-appfabric.aspx) about using it.

However, I don't think it's necessarily any easier to test.  Your best bet for testing is just running your Windows Service from the console.  That can be done by just instantiating your service object and exposing a method to start it.

Answer (score 1):

Give your console app some basic support for command line switches. Make the default (no switches) behavior to run as a service because the Windows service controller will run it this way. Add a -d switch to run in debug mode, which would just call the entry point to your actual service code instead of trying to run as a service. In VS, open the properties of your project, go to the Debug tab, and set your debug command line switch in the options when starting the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using Windows Azure Worker Roles instead. You get a running service like environment that is also hosted in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Try Windows scheduler. It's easy to start any program time based logic. And also easy to config any kind project like console or Windows forms.